# Angular 17 tailwindcss sass-loader

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, tailwind-css

After updating to Angular 17 an error with styles occurred:

```
./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
$color: theme("colors.primary.600") is not a color.
```

styles.scss

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Roboto&display=swap');
@import url('ag-grid-community/styles/agGridMaterialFont.css');

@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tp-theme/tp-theme";
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {

      primary: {
        600: '#0086C9',
      },
```

Everything is ok on the Angular v16

Comment: Are you sure you have defined "primary" color in your tailwind config? The error message clearly states that "primary" was not found in a colors list.

Comment: Yes in the tailwind.config.js I have a section

`
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: {
        25: '#F5FBFF',
        50: '#F0F9FF',
        75: '#E9F6FF',
        100: '#E0F2FE',
        150: '#D8EFFF',
        175: '#C7E4FF',
        200: '#B9E6FE',
        300: '#7CD4FD',
        400: '#36BFFA',
        500: '#0BA5EC',
        600: '#0086C9',
        700: '#026AA2',
        800: '#065986',
      },
`